# security check for a pdf file during upload in php

Tags: php, file-upload

i am trying to check the pdf before upload.

I want to check the pdf is malicious or not.

for example: i save a php file as pdf and upload it. but server shows an error that it is not a valid pdf.

so how can i check the pdf is real or not in php?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Fileinfo extension for php: http://www.php.net/fileinfo also example of usage here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php
L.E: Please note, FileInfo is the only way you should check your file types. Do not use their extensions to check against the file type, this is a huge mistake.
Also, if Fileinfo is not available for some reason and you cannot install it and you have shell access, you can just : `$info = exec('file -ib ' . escapeshellarg($filePath)); print_r($info);`

Comment: What is not working? You have the right answer. Please do your part and make sure you have fileinfo installed or that exec is enabled on your system. Simply checking for these is done by: `var_dump(function_exists('finfo_open'));` and `var_dump(function_exists('exec'));`